# How to access a keyvault that belongs to a different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Here's my components:

**Tenant A:**

1. Azure_WebApp_A
2. AAD multi tenant App registration
3. Keyvault_A

**Tenant B:**

1. Keyvault_B

**Background**: I'm able to access the secrets of **Keyvault_A** from **Azure_WebApp_A** using MSI authentication.
But when I try to add my multi tenant app registration(from Tenant A) to Keyvault_B's access policies, I don't even see the appId being detected there.

**Question**: How do I access secrets in the Keyvault_B from Azure_WebApp_A?

Comment: If you are using MSI authentication, what is multi tenant app for?

Comment: It is possible to add multi tenant app(from tenant A) to keyvault_B's access policy, if B tenant user has consent to use multi tenant app(tenant A), this app will exist under enterprise applications in tenant B.

Comment: Thanks @TonyJu for your response. To answer your first question, I had initially started with MSI, then realized that it won't work for my multi tenant scenario, so I tried using service principal authentication. The multi tenant AAD app is for that.
Can you also please share any references for how User in tenant B will gain the consent to use the multi tenant app A?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add multi tenant app(from tenant A) to keyvault_B's access policy, if B tenant user has consent to use multi tenant app(tenant A), this app will exist under enterprise applications in tenant B.

> How to grant consent to application?

When the user from A tenant sign in the application from tenant B, the application will then be registered under A tenant in enterprise applications.

[Requesting individual user consent.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent)

[Requesting consent for an entire tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant)

Comment: I think I've misunderstood your response. In  my scenario, all I want to do is service-to-service authentication between my TenantA app (which is going to be running as a backend job) and my KeyvaultB. The first link that you've posted seems to mention interactive login to provide consent. I don't understand how that's going to work when I deploy my app to Azure.

Comment: @IronMan To register a multi-tenant in another tenant, you need to do the consent. This is needed for the first time. And yes, it needs interactive login. After that, you will be able to choose the application in access policy.

Comment: @IronMan Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: I still haven't succeeded in getting this to work. I composed the consent url as follows and got the admin to run it on the browser: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-B-id/adminconsent?client_id=Azure_WebApp_A_clientid&state=12345&scope=/.default
This doesn't seem to work. Does the URL look correct?